# How to sort an array of dates (TDate) descending?

Tags: arrays, delphi, sorting, delphi-7

I have an `array[0..99] of TDate` and need to sort it, in descending order. I can't find an example anywhere, not even here on StackOverflow...

Btw, not all array items have a value. Most of the time, the array is filled with 10 to 30 values. I do not need a "super fast" way to do this, but the simplest / easier way...

Comment: What sort of solution you are asking for? What did you try yet? What was the problem with your solutions?

Comment: It has to be an array? Sorting TLists is almost automatic.

Comment: My answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/21699696/) has all you need

Comment: The same way you sort an array of anything else descending. Consult your algorithm textbook for a list of sorting algorithms. Nearly all of them are designed for sorting arrays. The type of thing stored in the array is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you have an array of TDates, rather than using a TList that Delphi provides for you, but I'll assume you are making some sort of test project, and you just need a quick and dirty way to sort your array. Here's a way to do it that will be more than quick enough for such a small array

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, DateUtils;

var
  A : array[0..99] of TDateTime;
  T : TDateTime; //Used to exchange dates
  I,J : integer;

begin
  //Initialize with some test data:
  for I := 0 to 99 do
    A[I] := DateOf(Now) - 365 + random(365);

  //Output the unsorted list:
  for I := 0 to 99 do
    writeln(DateToStr(A[I]));
  readln;

  //Here's our sorting algorithm (Bubble Sort, probably the easiest sorting algorithm to
  //understand, and the quickes to implement - but the worst sorting algorithm in actual use
  for I := 0 to 98 do //One less than the max index, but you really should use some constants
    for J := I+1 to 99 do //Up to the max index
      if A[I] < A[J] then //Change < to > to sort in ascending order
      begin
        T := A[I];     //We'll be overwriting A[I], so we should store the value
        A[I] := A[J];  //Here we overwrite A[I] with A[J]
        A[J] := T;     //And here we put T back in the new position
      end;

  //Output the sorted list:
  for I := 0 to 99 do
    writeln(DateToStr(A[I]));
  readln;
end.
```

I would *really* recommend using some other data structure (TList being the most obvious choice). Here's a way to do that:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, DateUtils, generics.collections;

var
  A : TList<TDate>;
  I : integer;
  T : TDate; 

begin
  A := TList<TDate>.Create;
  try
    for I := 0 to 99 do
      A.Add(DateOf(Now) - 365 + random(365));

    A.Sort; //Sorts in ascending order by default
    A.Reverse; //But you wanted descending order, so we'll reverse the list

    for T in A do
      writeln(DateToStr(T));
    readln;
  finally
    A.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: `TList<T>` not available in D7. Also, if you have generics then you use `TArray.Sort<T>` for array sorting.

Comment: What's more a sort followed by a reverse is wasteful. Better to use a custom comparer.