# Descending List box Items Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, sorting, delphi-xe8

I was reviewing some questions about how to sort list box items in a descending sequence.  It seem that the default and only sequence is ascending.  We do have the availability of the collection of string (TStringList).

It seems to me that if we insert the sort target to the collection list, perform a sort (in ascending order) but access the sorted items in descending order and add them to an unsorted list box item after the key is stripped off, that we receive the desired descending effect.

```
procedure TBCSLBDemoC.DescendLZB(var lb: TListBox);
var
  sc: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  rdt: TDateTime;
  buf : string;
begin
  sc := TStringList.Create;
  i := 0;
  repeat
    rdt := TFile.GetLastAccessTime(lb.Items[i]);
    sc.Add(FormatDateTime('YYYYMMDDHHMMSS', rdt) + ' ' + lb.Items[i]);
    Inc(i);
  until (i > (lb.Count - 1));
  sc.Sort;
  lb.Sorted := false;
  lb.Items.Clear;
  i := sc.Count - 1;
  repeat
    buf := sc[i];
    Delete(buf, 1, 15);
    lb.Items.Add(buf);
    dec(i);
  until (i < 0);
  sc.Free;
end;
```

These results seemed to work fine for me but my question is how would I improve upon this technique?  I believe I have overlooked something.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways you could tackle this problem. You have shown one method. You could switch to a virtual list box and store the data in a data structure that you kept ordered. You could sort the list in-place.

Personally I feel a little queasy looking at your code that creates a new list to perform the sorting. And even more queasy by your use of text representations of the time stamp. If you've got a large number of items in the list then virtual mode is more efficient.

However, I'll demonstrate a very flexible way to sort the list in-place. Let's start with the code from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21702570/505088. For the sake of being self-contained let's reproduce the code here, modified slightly to use reference procedures:

```
type
  TCompareIndicesFunction = reference to function(Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
  TExchangeIndicesProcedure = reference to procedure(Index1, Index2: Integer);

procedure QuickSort(Count: Integer; Compare: TCompareIndicesFunction; 
  Exchange: TExchangeIndicesProcedure);

  procedure Sort(L, R: Integer);
  var
    I, J, P: Integer;
  begin
    repeat
      I := L;
      J := R;
      P := (L+R) div 2;
      repeat
        while Compare(I, P)<0 do inc(I); 
        while Compare(J, P)>0 do dec(J); 
        if I<=J then 
        begin
          if I<>J then 
          begin
            Exchange(I, J);
            //may have moved the pivot so we must remember which element it is
            if P=I then
              P := J
            else if P=J then
              P := I;
          end;
          inc(I);
          dec(J);
        end;
      until I>J;
      if L<J then 
        Sort(L, J); 
      L := I;
    until I>=R;
  end;

begin
  if Count>0 then
    Sort(0, Count-1);
end;
```

The key idea here is that the sorting algorithm is separated from the data storage. That is what gives us flexibility.

Next we need to implement compare and exchange functions. Like this:

```
var
  Compare: TCompareIndicesFunction;
  Exchange: TExchangeIndicesProcedure;

Compare := 
  function(Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer
  var
    dt1, dt2: TDateTime;
  begin
    dt1 := TFile.GetLastAccessTime(lb.Items[Index1]);
    dt2 := TFile.GetLastAccessTime(lb.Items[Index2]);
    if dt1=dt2 then begin
      Result := 0;
    end else if dt2<dt1 then begin
      Result := -1
    end else begin
      Result := 1;
    end;
  end;

Exchange := 
  procedure(Index1, Index2: Integer)
  begin
    lb.Items.Exchange(Index1, Index2);
  end;
```

Note that I'm comparing the numeric value of the time stamp which feels much more pleasing. If I've got the order back to front (I always struggle with sort compare functions) then it should be obvious how to reverse it.

And finally we can sort like this:

```
QuickSort(lb.Count, Compare, Exchange);
```

This code should be placed inside your `DescendLZB` so that it can capture the list box. Furthermore, the `lb` parameter should not be a `var` parameter because you don't want to modify its value.

All together then it would look like this:

```
procedure TBCSLBDemoC.DescendLZB(lb: TListBox);
var
  Compare: TCompareIndicesFunction;
  Exchange: TExchangeIndicesProcedure;
begin
  Compare := 
    function(Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer
    var
      dt1, dt2: TDateTime;
    begin
      dt1 := TFile.GetLastAccessTime(lb.Items[Index1]);
      dt2 := TFile.GetLastAccessTime(lb.Items[Index2]);
      if dt1=dt2 then begin
        Result := 0;
      end else if dt2<dt1 then begin
        Result := -1
      end else begin
        Result := 1;
      end;
    end;

  Exchange := 
    procedure(Index1, Index2: Integer)
    begin
      lb.Items.Exchange(Index1, Index2);
    end;
  end;

  QuickSort(lb.Count, Compare, Exchange);
end;
```